# iPhone dev - why is it using 8MB?

Tags: memory-management, iphone

Even when I just use the Window-based application template, which does literally nothing, instruments (activity monitor) says my application's process is using 8.14MB of **Real Memory**! Even with this method:

```
void report_memory(void) {
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                   TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                   (task_info_t)&info,
                                   &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
        NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
    }
}
```

Its still ~8.14 MB! So it seems that instruments is right, but why would a UIWindow take up that much memory??

Comment: Maybe Apple's architecture isn't as good as people think it it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that it's the Objective-C runtime libraries that are taking up all that space, rather than your `UIWindow` itself. However, all applications use a copy of these libraries, the iPhone OS **may** be smart enough to share that memory among all of the applications that are running (although of course, only system apps are allowed to run in the background).